# Launch application on device boot with out delay

Tags: android, startup, boot

I want to launch the app when the device startup/boot complete. I saw many questions and solutions for this but nothing solved my problem perfectly. I follow some answers that says configurations changes in `manifest` file and `receiver` will do this, its working for me  but when the device boot completed it takes some second delay to launch my app. It shows device home screen and then only launch my app . In that short time delay user can access other applications from the device.

What I really need is an android device with only one app access and that app should launch automatically with out any time delay and user should not able to exit from the app and not able access any other thing in the device, it should show only my app interface.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the main activity in your app a Launcher, and set it as the default launcher on that device.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: i tried this method, it will launch the app on start up but take some delay to load.. it shows the home screen and then launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

in you manifest file set priority for receiver which invoked after boot like this :

inside

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="999" />
```

tag